# I can't seem to access packages I've installed inside the Nuget package installer for the solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, json.net, nuget, visual-studio-2019

Sorry if this is a basic question I am quite new and can't seem to figure out why this is an issue. Basically I've installed Newtonsoft.Json via the Nuget package manager inside of the project I'm working on in VS 2019 and it keeps coming back with CS0246 errors saying the namespace or type can't be found even though when I check it was successfully installed and is up to date. It's doing this with every package I install, any links to further reading that could help me figure this out would be great or if anyone has an idea of what is going on I'd be super grateful! Thanks so much.

Comment: Is there a small warning icon on referenced package in references? If there is - check output window on build.

Comment: 1) Double-check the install: `MSVS > Tools > NuGet > Manage NuGet Packages`: You should see something like "Installed 13.0.1, Project: CHECKED".  2) check your .csproj project file: you should see something like `<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />`  3) Go back into MSVS: `Build > Rebuild`.  If you get an error, look for "suggested fix" and try it: maybe you're just missing a "using" statement.  MSVS will fill it in for you.  4) Post back what you find.

Comment: @FoggyDay, So it looks like the packages are all there in the package manager and in the .csproj file. I did dig in and notice that all the using statements that seem to throw errors those packages are missing in my references folder. I've tried numerous things and times to try and get it to populate that folder, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the namespace or type needs to work in specified package version and the framework of the project.